# функция сравнения для сортировки массива

Tags: php

В php при сортировке массива чисел функция-компаратор выдает одинаковые результаты при использовании разных операторов сравнения.

```
<?php
  $arr1 = array(3, 1, 7, 6, 9, 4);
  usort($arr1, function($a, $b) { return $a <=> $b; });
  print_r($arr1); // Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 6 [4] => 7     
  //[5] => 9 )
  // ИЛИ
  $arr2 = array(3, 1, 7, 6, 9, 4);
  usort($arr2, function($a, $b) { return $a > $b; });
  print_r($arr2); // Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 6 [4] => 7 
  //[5] => 9 )
?>
```

Объясните пожалуйста поведение кода. Какой оператор предпочтительнее, для использования в функции-компараторе ">", "-",  "<=>", для сортировки по возрастанию массива чисел, почему? Возможно есть какие-то нюансы, влияющие на производительность данного кода?

Comment: выполните миллион сортировок и поймете, на глаз `<=> 0,29`, при `> 0,25`, обычный `sort 0,19`

Comment: разность и `<=>` по сути одно и то же. Вот строго больше по идее должно либо больше сравнений давать, либо неправильную сортировку, но проверяю, а одинаково все. надо на объектах сравнивать для наглядности а не числах. Ибо в числах не понятно, какое именно число с каким сравнивается и куда передвигается.

Comment: чет с объектами тоже все одинаково. мб нюансы используемой функции сортировки.